# What's the best approach for deleting the record: Laravel 5.2.15

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

## I am using Laravel 5.2.15.

There are list of records in a webpage with Edit and Delete button with each record. I have two approaches for deleting the record

1. Use JQuery and send Ajax Request to server.
2. Place a form tag for delete button in each row.
   I have following question

> 1. In case I use Approach 1, can it cause any issue when the site will be viewed from Android or iPhone? I have another option to do Server side validation using Request class.
> 2. In case of Approach 2, Will it make the page heavy? I am using Pagination, so 10 records will be displaced per page.
> 3. Please guide me if I should go with which approach or please suggest if both approaches are incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

The questions you have don't really focus on the main reasons to choose one above the other. They differ mostly in how the request is sent to the server and how the page is refreshed to show the results.

Using Ajax is a very common approach and relies on using Javascript, a technology that has been available in all browsers for a very long time. Compatibility will not be a problem as most of the internet wouldn't function without it anyways (and you can even make it work using your second approach as a fallback mechanism). The request you sent is typically a HTTP DELETE request to a [REST endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) so that the server then knows to delete the record<sup>1</sup>. Upon receiving the success response from the server the page is responsible for updating itself by removing the row corresponding with the just deleted record, and possibly fetching new records to still have 10 rows on that page. No page refreshes required, but some Javascript required.

Your second approach is kind of old school in that the form you submit contains some kind of identifier such that the server knows what to do. This is a full page load and should be a HTTP POST request if you want to do it properly<sup>2</sup>. Following the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) idiom the server then sends a Redirect response so that the browser will then trigger yet another normal page load as GET request to show the user the updated list of records. You do not have to update the page manually by yourself, at the cost of having annoying page reloads (this isn't really expected anymore in the current day and age).

My advise would be to go with the first approach. It is the modern way of doing things and allows for having non-reloading pages. It does however require some additional work on the client side (in Javascript) to update the page accordingly.

As a side note, CSRF must be taken care of in both instances really. Always include a CSRF token with every 'update' action you perform on the server.

---

<sup>1</sup> You have to program this yourself, of course :)

<sup>2</sup> Browsers don't generally support anything other than GET and POST, although the HTTP specification allows for much more request methods.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your requirements. But you should go with the 1st approch. If you will use 2nd approch the you will have to refresh the page since you can not handle the response. So basically if you delete 5 items the page needs to be refreshed 5 times and you may not send more than 1 delete request at a time. Now If you use 1st approch since It's `ajax` and `javascript` you can display appropriate message depending upon the result and no need of unnecessary page refresh.Plus as you mentioned you can do validaton using `Request` class. So you can handle bad or malicious request. And I am sure `CSRF` won't be that much of a problem since you can check whether the request is ajax or not using `Request::ajax()`. So 1st approch is better mostly because of that no page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are fine ;)

> But 2nd approach would be better than first one; Using this approach you can prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks too;

Comment: Aren't both susceptible to csrf if not handled correctly? and besides, laravel has a built-in csrf token mechanism which you could add to if you feel a bit unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use method 1 with certain modifications.

- Use get request to delete the record.
- Send a CSRF token and dont forget to encrypt your id for the record
- add your delete URL to href

Then when you do ajax request, use the url from href and you could send some additional parameter like is_ajax=1, but laravel already checks for the jquery header so `Request::isAjax()` method will let you know if the request was an ajax request or normal request.

Now all you need to do is send different response for ajax and normal request.

HOPE THIS HELPS :D

Comment: Why not just use delete verb?

Answer (score 0):

Another drawback of your second approach which haven't been mentioned is displaying validation errors. Specifically from your edit and even your delete actions.

If you have multiple forms for each set of data showing errors from validation would be a pain. But if you follow approach number 2 just by getting the reference of the row element submitted, you could easily append an alert div if ever an error from validation has occurred.

as for the delete action, somebody else might have already delete some shared data so you might also want to tell the user somebody already threw this out.